# Keep on adding dynamic height text view in scroll view on button click

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

I am preparing a form in which we have to add a UI Text View on every button click. This text view must increase its height as text is typed and scroll view should increase its content size accordingly. 
I have tried using UITableView for this with scrolling enabled = false and placing text view inside cell with scrolling enabled = false. Now I am trying to increase content size for table view as well as scroll view with the addition of new cell on every button click but unable to do so. Can anyone help with this ?

```
var notesArray = [String]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if notesArray.count == 0{
        return 1
    }else{
        return notesArray.count
    }
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell : AddAssetCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddAssetCell", for: indexPath) as! AddAssetCell
    cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.txtView.delegate = self
    if notesArray.count > 0{
        cell.txtView.text = notesArray[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

    let startHeight = textView.frame.size.height
    let calcHeight = textView.sizeThatFits(textView.frame.size).height 
    if startHeight != calcHeight {

        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false) // Disable animations
        self.tableViewNotes.beginUpdates()
        self.tableViewNotes.endUpdates()

        let scrollTo = self.tableViewNotes.contentSize.height - self.tableViewNotes.frame.size.height
        self.tableViewNotes.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x : 0, y : scrollTo), animated: false)
        contraintHeightTblViewNotes.constant = self.tableViewNotes.contentSize.height
        self.scrollViewAddAsset.contentSize.height = self.scrollViewAddAsset.contentSize.height + scrollTo
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)  // Re-enable animations.
    }
}

//MARK: - Text View Delegates
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.textColor == UIColor.lightGray {
        textView.text = nil
        textView.textColor = UIColor.black
    }
}
func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView.text.isEmpty {
        textView.text = "Notes"
        textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    }else{
        if notesArray.count > 0 {
            notesArray.insert(textView.text, at: notesArray.count - 1)
        }else{
            notesArray.append(textView.text)
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func btnAddMoreAction(_ sender: Any) 
{

    notesArray.append("")
    tableViewNotes.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Here is link may be help you => https://github.com/paresh1994/TextViewInsideTableView

Comment: this example shows static data. But I have to compute the content size every time when text view changes

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's talk a little bit about **Self-Sizing** **Cell** in UITableView, if you haven't known it, here is a clear tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells.

It let your UITableView grown it cell height automatically in summarization. So the next challenge is UITextViewDelegate, here is my favorite solution when facing **Self-Sizing** **UITextView**.:

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView === txtDescription, textView.text == txtDescripttionPlaceHolder {
        textView.text = nil
        textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(0, 0)
    }
}

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    let newLenght = textView.text.count + text.count - range.length
    if textView === txtDescription, textView.text == txtDescripttionPlaceHolder, newLenght > 0 {
        if text.count == 0 {
            return false
        }
        textView.text = nil
    }
    return true
}

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView === txtDescription {
        resizeTxtDescription()
    }
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    if textView == txtDescription {
        textView.text.trimNewlinesAndWhitespaces()
        textView.text = textView.text.count > 0 ? textView.text : txtDescripttionPlaceHolder
        resizeTxtDescription()
    }
}

private func resizeTxtDescription() {
    let fixedWidth = self.txtDescription.frame.size.width
    self.txtDescription.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    let newSize = txtDescription.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { [weak self] in
        self?.txtDescriptionHeightConstraint.constant = newSize.height
        self?.view.setNeedsLayout()
        self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

After setting up your UITableViewCell, declaring a constraint keep your UITextView Height like **txtDescriptionHeightConstraint** in my situation, so you can change your UITextView height via changing the constraint's constant.